# Traffic flow modelling - How to identify fans/shocks?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

> A highway contains a uniform distribution of cars moving at maximum flux in the $x$-direction, which is unbounded
>   in $x$. Measurements show that the car velocity $v$ obeys the relation: $v = 1 − ρ$, where ρ is the number
>   of cars per unit length. An on-ramp is built into the highway in the region $0 ≤ x < 1$. Town planners want to
>   understand whether they should limit the rate per unit length of cars, $α$, entering the highway via this on-ramp,
>   to avoid traffic jams on the highway. The on-ramp is closed for all time $t < 0$, and opens for $t ≥ 0$.
>
> Identify the presence of all key features of the problem, including any fans/shocks.

Hi, can someone please explain to me how to do such a question? I'm struggling to understand this conceptually, the process of identifying fans and shocks, what exactly I'm supposed to be looking for. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macroscopic traffic-flow model by Lighthill-Whitham-Richards (LWR) is an hydrodynamic model for traffic flow on a single infinite road. It consists in a scalar hyperbolic conservation law, which represents the conservation of cars (continuity equation):
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}Q (\rho) = 0 \, ,
$$
where the flux $Q(\rho) = \rho\, v(\rho)$ depends only on the density of cars $\rho$. The simplest expression for the car velocity $v(\rho)$, introduced by Greenshields, reads
$$
v(\rho) = v_\max \left(1 - \frac{\rho}{\rho_\max}\right) .
$$
Therefore, the present case corresponds to $v_\max = 1$ m/s and $\rho_\max=1$ car/m. The flux function $Q (\rho) = \rho \left(1- \rho\right)$ is maximum at $\rho = 1/2$ car/m, which is assumed to be the uniform density of cars at negative times. The characteristic curves such that $\rho(x,t)=\rho(x(t),t)$ satisfy
$$
\frac{d\rho}{dt} = \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + \underbrace{\frac{dx}{dt}}_{Q'(\rho)} \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x} = \alpha \boldsymbol{1}_{0\leq x(t) < 1,\, t\geq 0} \, ,
$$
where $\alpha$ is the rate per unit length of cars entering the highway via an on-ramp. Several cases are considered:

- For times $t<0$, $\rho=1/2$ and $dx/dt = 1 - 2\rho = 0$. The space-time diagram is made of vertical lines, on which the car density is constant.
- When the ramp is turned on, i.e. $t\geq 0$, one has $d\rho/dt = \alpha$, i.e. $\rho = \alpha t + 1/2$ over the ramp. The characteristics satisfy $dx/dt = 1 - 2 \rho = -2\alpha t$. Therefore, over the on-ramp, the space-time diagram is made of non-crossing decreasing functions, on which the car density is *not* constant. Qualitatively, these curves will interact with the vertical lines in the following way:

  - a left-going shock wave is created on the left of the ramp: the upstream cars stop suddenly;
  - a left-going rarefaction wave (fan) is created on the right of the ramp: the inserted cars accelerate gradually, until they reach the maximum-flux velocity.

A more quantitative solution is possible. At this point, one can decide to solve the conservation law with source term
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}Q (\rho) = \alpha \boldsymbol{1}_{0\leq x < 1,\, t\geq 0}
$$
numerically, or to have a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2262003/traffic-flow-modelling-highway-entrance-case).

Comment: I think the question wants us to do this without derivation. Because the next question asks: (c) Calculate the characteristics, any related shocks/fans, car density and hence plot the space-time diagram.Using this diagram, give a mathematical expression for the density, ρ(x, t). Hint: A complicated first-orderdifferential equation will require solution. First determine x(0) and x'(0), then use the leading-order term in aseries solution for x(t).

Comment: Thank you so much! Very concise and easy to understand

Comment: Do any of you know how to calculate what you've mentioned in the comment Brock? ie the characteristics, shocks/fans, car density and how to use the space-time diagram to calculate p(x,t). I'm also stuck on this problem. Calculating the shocks/fans is what's troubling me most.

Comment: Okay, I've asked a new question, thank you.

Comment: I was hoping you'd be able to help with it, if you have the time of course. There doesn't seem to be many on here familiar with this area