# Method of characteristics with discontinuous source term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

Let's say I have the system of equations $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\mathrm{d}t} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\beta, \hspace{3mm}  x < 0 \\ 
0, \hspace{3mm} x \geq 0 
\end{matrix}\right.,
\\ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = 1-2\rho
$$

With the initial condition $ \rho(x,0) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1/2, \hspace{3mm}  x < 1 \\ 
1, \hspace{3mm} x \geq 1 
\end{matrix}\right. $

edit: $\beta$ is a positive constant.
How would I go about solving this? A general outline is fine I would not like a detailed working. For context, this is in an attempt to solve the PDE $$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + (1-2\rho)\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\beta, \hspace{3mm}  x < 0 \\ 
0, \hspace{3mm} x \geq 0 
\end{matrix}\right.,$$
using the method of characteristics.

EDIT: 
As @EditPiAf points out, the characteristics for $x < 0$ are given by $x = x_0 -\beta t^2$, along which $\rho = 1/2 + \beta t$, here the first issue arises. which is what happens after $t = 1/2\beta$? The shock emanating from $x = 1$ will reach the $x < 0$ region at $t =2$, resulting in another shock, defined by $x_s$. But what actually is the form of the characteristics in this region (neighbourhood of $x=0^-, t=2$)? I would think that they are  given by $x = -\beta(t-t_0)^2$ but I can't rigorously justify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the traffic flow equation with a car source of strength $β>0$ over $\Bbb R−$, which is somewhat similar to the [on-ramp problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2262003). Let's apply the method of characteristics.

- characteristic curves $t\mapsto (x(t),t)$ starting at $x_0<0$ satisfy $\dot x=1-2\rho$ with $\dot \rho=\beta$, i.e. the curves are of the form $x = x_0 - \beta t^2$ along which $\rho = \frac12 +\beta t$.
- characteristics starting at $0\le x_0<1$ are vertical lines $x = x_0$ along which $\rho = \frac12$.
- characteristics starting at $1\le x_0$ are the lines $x = x_0 - t$ along which $\rho = 1$.

Characteristics intersect around $x=1$. A left-going shock wave with Rankine-Hugoniot speed $s = -1/2$ is produced. Characteristics separate around $x=0$. Similarly to the highway entrance problem, the discontinuity of the source term creates an artificial boundary between two road segments with different behavior, that might be expressed by the condition $\rho|_{x=0}=1/2$.

- characteristics starting at $0<t_0$ from the line $x=0$ satisfy $\rho = \frac12 + \beta (t-t_0)$ and $x = -\beta(t-t_0)^2$.

At some point ($t=2$), the shock wave will cross the vertical line $x=0$. Before this happens ($t<2$), the solution reads
$$
\rho(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&\tfrac12 + \beta t & &\text{if} \quad x<-\beta t^2\\
&\tfrac12 + \sqrt{-\beta x} & &\text{if} \quad {-\beta t^2}\le x< 0\\
&\tfrac12 & &\text{if} \quad 0\le x< 1-\tfrac12 t\\
&1 & & \text{if}\quad 1-\tfrac12 t < x 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
From $t=2$, the Rankine-Hugoniot shock speed $\dot x_s$ is given by the differential equation
$$
\dot x_s(t) = \frac{\frac14 + \beta x_s(t) - 0}{\frac12 + \sqrt{-\beta x_s(t)} - 1},
\qquad
x_s(2) = 0 \, ,
$$
which solution
$$
x_s(t) = -\frac1{4\beta}\left(1 + W\big({-e}^{-1-\beta(t-2)}\big)\right)^2
$$
is expressed using the product-log function (Lambert's $W$-function).
The solution for times $t>2$ reads
$$
\rho(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&\tfrac12 + \beta t & &\text{if} \quad x<-\beta t^2\\
&\tfrac12 + \sqrt{-\beta x} & &\text{if} \quad {-\beta t^2}\le x< x_s(t)\\
&1 & & \text{if}\quad x_s(t) < x
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes so far I'm with you. There are some issues I'm facing however that are not really addressed in other related posts. See the updated OP for details.

Comment: @Enforce Answer updated!